# How to multiply last 2 columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to define cells function in excel as:

cell[i][j] = cell[i][j - 1] * cell[i][j - 2]

Where i is row, and j is column?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: =PRODUCT(INDEX(ROW(), COLUMN()-2), INDEX(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. What is wrong with just `=A1*B1` in cell `C1` and copying and pasting wherever you need it. OR is this a VBA question? It's very unclear.

Comment: I have a lot of rows, and I want it to be automatic if possible

Comment: What does "Automatic" mean in this context? You can create a table and then add that formula in a new column of the table and it will propagate down the rows for you. Or you can just add that formula in the next column and copy it down.

Comment: You could use `OFFSET`: `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1)*OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-2)`. However, I'm not clear on what you're actually looking for

Comment: OR... are you saying that you have many rows and each row has a different number of columns populated and you want whatever the first unoccupied column is in that row to contain the product of the last two populated columns? If that's the case some VBA will be required. Please share some sample (A screenshot) of some of these rows and what your expected output is.

Comment: Change Formula type to R1C1, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

MATCH(1e99, 2:2) returns the column number of the last number in row 2. This can be used with INDEX to return the last number. Subtracting 1 from that MATCH position should give you the second-to-last.

```
=index(2:2, match(1e99, 2:2)-1)*index(2:2, match(1e99, 2:2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the cleanest, but the below works.

If you change the A1:AZ1 to whatever the max column range could be.
Then you can drag down and get the calc for each row.

```
    =LOOKUP(2,1/((A1:AZ1<>LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:AZ1<>""),A1:AZ1))*(A1:AZ1<>"")),A1:AZ1)*LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:AZ1<>""),A1:AZ1)
```

This will give you the data in last non-blank column on the row;

```
    =LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:AZ1<>""),A1:AZ1)
```

and this is for the second last non-blank column in the row (notice that it references the above after the first "<>";

```
    =LOOKUP(2,1/((A1:AZ1<>LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:AZ1<>""),A1:AZ1))*(A1:AZ1<>"")),A1:AZ1)
```

then just multiply both and you have the top formula.
As I said, it is not the cleanest but it does what you need.